# Mp3 tags from file names?

Tags: mp3, tag, id3

When I rip audiobook CD's to MP3's, the tracks get mixed up. Disks are not always properly tagged - I believe to discourage automated ripping and illegal copying.
It appears MP3Tag will do the job, but it's a Windows program, isn't it?
Is there an equivalent for Ubuntu?

Thanks

CP

Comment: MP3Tag works well enough through Wine: http://askubuntu.com/a/752877/57576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best mp3 tag editor for ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976627/what-is-the-best-mp3-tag-editor-for-ubuntu-17-10). Almost all mp3 tagger software (either with GUI and for CLI) have this feature.

Answer (score 5):

Ex Falso is a graphical application that can generate MP3 tags for multiple files from their filenames. Ex Falso can generate tags for all the songs in one album at the same time. Here is an example of generating a tag pattern of three tags from the filename of an MP3 file in Ex Falso:

[image]

The generated tags under the *Tags From Path* tab in Ex Falso for this example song are:

- 01
- name of artist
- name of song

Another convenient feature of Ex Falso is that if you have an album with filenames in an irregular pattern, you can rename multiple files backwards from their tags under the *Rename Files* tab.

---

[image: change tag from filename in EasyTAG]
<sup>generate tags from filename in EasyTAG (`sudo apt install easytag`)</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to generate a tag for the file: **05. Adele - Someone Like You.mp3**  >>> **Adele - 05. Someone Like You**. Any idea?

Comment: @MuratYıldız To perform this task use EasyTAG (`sudo apt install easytag`). Select file(s), click the gear icon (Show Scanner) and click the *Scan Files* button as shown in the screenshot which I addded to this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I tried this before asking the question and I need to move track number after artist. Is it possible to do this? Also, how can I remove any info and add custom info to the tag? For example to generate tag from file by removing **05** and adding **[Live]** : 05. Adele - Someone Like You.mp3 >>> Adele - Someone Like You [Live].

Comment: @MuratYıldız Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031003). The same application also adds a right-click (batch or individual) rename option to Files files manager.

Comment: Is it just for file renaming or can it rename Mp3 tag from file as I mentioned above from 05. Adele - Someone Like You.mp3 to Adele - Someone Like You [Live] by using file name? And I also need to insert some custom word inside the tag?

Comment: GPRename easily can replace, remove, insert, delete and number consecutively files and directories (just for file renaming). Easy TAG is for tag editing.

Comment: As I use Windows, I try some other tools like GPRename that also suitable for tag editing. So, there is no need to base on some tools that is dedicated to ID3 Tag editing. Thanks a lot for your helps.

Comment: Worth noting that there's a plugin in ExFalso to do audio fingerprint lookup, and it's pretty good. @karel

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list generated from running the command:

```
apt-cache search mp3 | grep tags
```

Hint, GTK apps have a GUI.

```
easytag - GTK+ editor for audio file tags
eyed3 - Display and manipulate id3-tags on the command-line
id3tool - Command line editor for id3 tags
libjaudiotagger-java - library for editing tags like ID3 in audio files such as MP3s
libmp3-tag-perl - Module for reading tags of MP3 audio files
mp3rename - Rename mp3 files based on id3tags
python-eyed3 - Python module for id3-tags manipulation
python-id3 - Python module for id3-tags manipulation
python-tagpy - Python module for manipulating tags in music files
ruby-mp3tag - Ruby library for manipulating ID3V1.1 tags in MP3
swac-scan - Metatags scanner for SWAC audio collections
taggrepper - search and match tags of audio files against regular expressions
```

It looks like `easytag` is what you are looking for.

Run the following commands to install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install easytag
```

or just install it from the ubuntu software center.