# Is there an app to remove tag write protection on audio files?

Tags: music, metadata

On Windows I used 'Mp3tag' to remove both metadata and protection in order to write other metadata. Is there an equivalent on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives for mp3tag but it seems to run well enough using Wine under Trusty Tahr so perhaps try this? I found that the Trusty repository Wine failed but a newer copy from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) worked absolutely perfectly with mp3tag:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks
```

Then download the newest mp3tag from the website and install by double clicking on the downloaded archive. Results on my system:

[image]