# How to batch edit mp3 tag properties ubuntu?

Tags: mp3, tag, id3

I already installed Easytag on my Ubuntu but It's not good for editing multiple files. I want to change mp3 property information on multiple files. Does anyone know how to batch edit multiple mp3 files?

Answer (score 10):

Ex Falso from the default Ubuntu repositories is more full featured for batch editing of .mp3 tags than EasyTAG. To install Ex Falso open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install exfalso
```

The main thing that I use Ex Falso for is to generate song titles automatically from their file names. Ex Falso also shows additional tags that are not shown in EasyTAG, and it also lets you make your own customized tags.

Comment: any options for adding a cover of album?

Comment: Not in Ex Falso. In EasyTAG select the Images tab and then click the green **+** icon at the bottom to add an album cover to a song. You need to add the images one song at a time, however you can select all the songs in an album and save the changes with a single click when you are done adding the album cover to all the songs in an album. I have both EasyTAG and Ex Falso installed because I use them both.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: EasyTag can also fill in tags (such as artist, title, album, track number) from file names. Conversely, it can also rename files based on these tags.

Comment: Yes but the **Show scanner** options in EasyTAG look like chicken scratch and I prefer to use the dropdown menu in Ex Falso because all the options in the dropdown **Tags from Path** menu are listed by their names so I can click to select the option that I want instead of typing a line of symbols in EasyTAG.

Answer (score 1):

Clementine just did the trick for me. Highlight the batch you want to change. Right click and choose Edit track information. Edit the tag or tags of choice. Note that it says the song titles are different across multiple songs. Save.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a single tag for a large number of MP3 files, it's probably best to do it on the command line.

The program `id3v2` allows command line editing of MP3 (*id3*) tags:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install id3v2
```

Test out `id3v2` to ensure you're happy it's doing the edit you need and the result is exactly what you want:

```
id3v2 --TIT3 "Updated tag!" test_file.mp3
```

At this point, check that *test_file.mp3* looks how you expect.

Use the find command to identify all the files you would like to edit. In simplest, this might look like:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3'
```

Check the output of this command identifies all the files you want to edit (and none that you don't). Once happy, use the find command to run the id3v2 program on all mp3 files:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3' -exec id3v2 --TIT3 "Updated tag!" '{}' \;
```

I've made this post quite verbose but, once you've done this a few times, you'll find the techniques far quicker and more powerful than using a GUI renamer.